# Why isnt the offspring or progeny of Mirza Ghulam ahmed not Ahmedi prophets

Tags: prophets, messengers, ahmadiyyah

The immediate offspring of Adam, Seth, was a prophet.

Ibrahim had Ismail and Isaac as sons and prophets.

Isaac had Yaqub and Yaqub had Yusuf.

Dawud had Sulayman.

From the progeny of Ismail bin Ibrahim we have Muhammad. (Peace be upon them )

The offspring or progeny of Mirza Ghulam Ahmed the Ahmadiyyah prophet aren't considered prophets but caliphs. Why is this distinction made? Given that he had 2 sons who reached adulthood and he was paternal grandfather to boys.

Comment: Only one downvote accounted. One more downvote added

Answer (score 0):

The question is particular to the Ahmadiyyah sect because Sunni and all Shia Muslim agree that Muhammad (p.b.u.h) is the last prophet and no later prophet is to be expected.

According to Sunni understanding, the prophets have been appointed by God only. It is not necessary that the son of a prophet is also a prophet.

The group of people counted among the messengers (rasil) is smaller than the group of smaller prophets (Nabi). Dawud and Suleiman are usually not counted among the rasul and Suleiman is not always counted among the Nabi.

Comment: Dawud got zabur right? Still he isnt considered prophet why?

Comment: Dawud is mentioned in the Quran after the prophets, saying "we gave Dawud the Psalm". So he is acknowledged receiving the word from God but he is somehow not the same as the messengers mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Mirza Ghulam Ahmed(Mirza Kafir Lanti) is not muslim as he clearly goes against the Ayat "Muhammad is not the father of any of your men, but (he is) the Messenger of Allah, and the Seal of the Prophets: and Allah has full knowledge of all things." Along with denying the Quran he also disrespected a lot Prophets. Especially Prophet Esa and he also disrespected Prophet Esa's righteous mom. He denied the Quran and disrespected Prophets(which is kufr). If you think he is a Prophet, nauzubillah, then I heard its open/clear kufr. Anyone who believes that there can be or there is a Prophet after our Prophet Muhammad Sallahu Alihe Wasallam is a disbeliever. Ask like a Mufti about your situation